# Strict or similar option for DateTime Parsing

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-4.0, datetime-parsing

I have a code that looks like code below in a PC which runs fine:

```
DateTime.Parse("10/10/2012");
```

I copied it over to other machine and it says something blaming the date conversion is wrong.
What I had to do to work around it is to use:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("10/10/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Does anyone know if there is any configuration in c# or the machine that control this such things? (or it might be .net version different between the two computers? but i am pretty sure they are the same in both machine as I used Ms Visual Studio 2008 for both machine).

I am talking about global configuration on windows itself that makes some strict exceptions to my programs. Anyone knows about this?

Comment: Check the Regional and languages settings of your Windows system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(You're mixing `ParseExact` and `TryParseExact`.)

The differences come from the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.Different parts of the world write dates in different ways.

Even saying `ParseExact("10/10/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", null)` can be problematic. Have you tried first setting

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
```

and then doing the above `ParseExact`? It will fail because the `DateSeparator` is not `"/"` in this culture. To fix it, either say

```
DateTime.ParseExact("10/10/2012", @"dd\/MM\/yyyy", null)
```

or say

```
DateTime.ParseExact("10/10/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

The first works by "escaping" the slash `/` so it becomes a literal slash and is not translated to the current `DateSeparator`. The second one works by giving the invariant culture where we know that the `DateSeparator` is indeed `"/"`.

**Addition:**

If you never set `CurrentCulture` in your code, its value depends on the **Regional and language settings** of your operating system. I suppose you're running Windows? Details might depend on exact Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

The system's current culture is used when parsing dates. I would bet that the two machines have different cultures.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is always the same (say en-us format) and you want to abstract away from user date&time formatting preferences then `DateTime.TryParseExact` is a good, proper way to go.

Comment: the problem is it is bugging my others programs as well (I have another code that is passing a nullable int onto a function and in the problematic machine it says invalid specified cast of the argument while it works fine in the good machine). im might be looking into something like a specific machine config here if you know any? Thanks tho for the reply

Comment: @Chris'o: what is the source or nature of the input?

Comment: text file for the date, and for the nullable argument of the function is a database result set. ring a bell?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to set cultural invariant date time:-

```
 using System.Globalization;
//...
 DateTime _datetime = DateTime.Now;
string _formattedDateTime = _datetime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("s", 
DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) + "Z";
```

Comment: Use just `u` instead, and no fancy string concatenation will be necessary.